# Second order edge detection - 1D Filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have to filter image (grayscale) with 1 dimensional filter given by diffrence equation:

```
y[n] = x[n+1]-2x[n]+x[n-1]
```

using convolution which should work as edge detector. I know that I need to filter rows (or columns) of orginal image first and then apply filter to columns (or rows) on it. But what should I actually convolute ? Could anyone give me some tips how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first derive the impulse response from difference equation: in your case, `h = [1 -2 1]`.

You then convolve your matrix, say `img`, with the impulse response twice (once along each dimension). For that, use the three-parameter version of [`conv2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html):

```
filtered_img = conv2(h, h, img);
```